# How do I include a quadratic time trend to a plm fixed effects model in R?

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, trend

I am working with an unbalanced panel of 16 entities and 38 years. So far, I've simply used the plm() twoways specification for my panel and I clustered heteroscedastic standard errors at the state level. Now, I'd like to include a state-specific quadratic time trend.

So far, I've tried to do it with a variable stating the years of the observations for each state from 1980 to 2019 in a monochronic order and just included this variable as explaining variable:

```
fixed_trend <- plm(X ~ Y + Z + time + time^2, data = df, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
summary(fixed_trend, vcovHC(fixed_trend, type="HC3", cluster="group"))
```

The output of this regression, however, doesn't show the trends. It only gives me the coefficients of my explaining variables (in this example, hence, Y and Z). Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: With `effect="twoways"`, the model is estimating time fixed-effects, too.  After doing that, there's no systematic variation left relating to time, so the model would be unable to estimate time trends in addition to time fixed-effects.

Comment: Thank's for your comment! I've already read about this and it makes sense but many papers do fixed effects with time trends... but maybe then at another level than states? However, in my case I tried to do it with effect = "time" right now, and still R doesn't give me the coefficients for trends. Another idea? :)

Comment: Try with `effect="individual"` which will do unit fixed effects and should allow you to model the time-trend.